# Supertest giving 415 response to testing express app POST Method

Tags: express, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to test the following a post method url of my express router using supertest.
Alll the other post method tests work fine and they are basically the same. I tested the url with curl and it also worked fine, I immediately went and retried the supertest test and it failed again with a 415.

Here is my 
supertest method:

```
        request(app)
            .post('/createSet')
            .send({'user_id': 1, 'setname':'TESTSET', 'description':'TESTRUN'})
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end( (err,res) => {
                if(err) { return done(err); }
                expect(res.status).toBe(200);
```

Once it gets to the 200 assertion it fails with the following messege:

> **::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [09/May/2020:23:02:35 +0000] "POST /createSet
>   HTTP/1.1" 415 471 "-" "node-superagent/3.8.3"
>   /Users/bisesma/LearnOrDie_4/node_modules/expect/build/index.js:336
>         throw error;
>         ^
>
> JestAssertionError: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is
>   equality
>
> Expected: 200 Received: 415
>   at Test. (/Users/bisesma/LearnOrDie_4/lib/apiUnit.test.js:203:36)
>   at Test.Object..Test.assert (/Users/bisesma/LearnOrDie_4/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:181:6)
>   at Server.localAssert (/Users/bisesma/LearnOrDie_4/node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:131:12)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:28)
>   at Server.emit (events.js:316:20)
>   at emitCloseNT (net.js:1657:8)
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {   matcherResult: {
>
> actual: 415,
>   expected: 200,
>   message: [Function (anonymous)],
>   name: 'toBe',
>   pass: false   } }

BUT ! the following curl worked perfectly:

```
 curl -d '{"user_id":1, "setname":"TESTSET","description":"THIS WAS CREATED FOR A TEST RUN"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:4242/createSet
```

I think it's something to do with supertest. I have several other test methods with the same setup that pass.

Here's my server method:

```
router.post('/createSet', async (req,res) => {
  logger('Creating a card set...');
  const user_id = req.body.user_id;
  const cardsInSet = req.body.cards;
  const setname = req.body.setname;
  const setDesc = req.body.description;
  const _desc = setDesc.replace(`'`,`\'`);
  const _setname = setname.replace(`'`,`\'`);
  // Create the CardSet, get it's ID
  const cardsetResult = await dataDAO.runQuery(queries.insertCardSet,[_setname, _desc]);
  const cardsetId = cardsetResult.insertId;
  logger(`cardset result: ${JSON.stringify(cardsetResult)}`);
  // with that and the user_id, Create the CardSetUser get its ID
  // This table won't have an ID
  const csuserResult = await dataDAO.runQuery(queries.insertCardSetUser,[user_id,cardsetId]);
  logger(`cardsetUser result: ${JSON.stringify(csuserResult)}`);
  if(csuserResult.affectedRows !== 1 ){ fail(`/createSet: something went wrong with card set: ${cardsetId}\n inserting csu: ${user_id}`); }
  // For Every card create a CardSetCard with the set_id and card_id
  let cscardRes;
  for(let j = 0; j < cardsInSet.length; j++) {
     cscardRes = await dataDAO.runQuery(queries.insertCardSetCard,[cardsInSet[j],cardsetId]);
     if(cscardRes.affectedRows !== 1) {fail(`/createSet: someting went wrong with card set: ${cardsetId}\n inserting card: ${cardsInSet[j].card_id}`);}
  }
  // Send back setID name descirption and array of IDs
  res.status(200).type('application/json').send({'set_id':cardsetId, 'setname':setname, 'description':setDesc, 'cards':cardsInSet});
});[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Here's the full test method:

```
    test.only('Create card set', async(done) => {
        // Test data
        const dataDAO = new DAO();
        const testCards = [];
        let results = await dataDAO.runQuery('SELECT * FROM FlashCards WHERE owner_id = 1 LIMIT 10');
        //logger(` ==> ${JSON.stringify(results)} -- `);
        for(let i =0; i < 10; i++) {
            testCards.push(results[i]);
        }
        request(app)
            .post('/createSet')
            .send({'user_id':'1', 'setname':'TESTSET', 'cards':testCards, 'description':'THIS WAS CREATED FOR A TEST RUN'})
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end( (err,res) => {
                if(err) { return done(err); }
                expect(res.status).toBe(200);
                expect(res.body.set_id).toBeDefined();
                expect(res.body.description).toBe('THIS WAS CREATED FOR A TEST RUN');
                expect(res.body.cards.length).toBe(10);
                expect(res.body.setname).toBe('TESTSET');
                logger(` test Create Card Set: ${res.body.set_id} `);
                testSetId = res.body.set_id;
            });

        done();
    });
```

I just ran that test again here's a screen shot of the 415:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete, reproducible code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 added some code and a screenshot. It has to be something with supertest, I've never used it until now but all other methods pass. I can also confirm that this server method works when using the app normally. Thanks!

Comment: i'm running into the same 415 issue, my supertest is 6.2.4